# atom feed: Empty Feed or 404?

Tags: xml, feed, atom-feed

We have a REST server which returns Feed (ATOM) based on the input query. For certain query parameters (valid/invalid) the Feed contains zero entries. For zero entries should an empty feed be returned or 404? Is there a standard way this is handled?

Any pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

If the query is truly invalid, i.e. it can never return any results by the logic of your webapp, then you should return an error. If there's just nothing to report *yet*, then an empty feed would be appropriate.